# mysql database and multiple users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a web site that will have multiple users. Say 5 users total.What I need to make sure is, that each user will only be able to access the data they input.

Think of a CRM or Job Board. So john will only be able to access johns info, edit, add, etc. Same with jane and june.

Now if my reading is correct, all i need to do is make sure the queries pull only the data based off their unique id correct?

so the database table for the users looks like:

```
Database: xxxxx, Table: xh_user
user_id 
user_username
user_fname
users_email
users_password 
users_salt
```

so if johns user_id is 7, when he logs in, it queries his id and displays only his content from the database.

Am i correct on this?, or is there a different or better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes that's correct. But make sure you use the logged in guy's id on the backend, probably using sessions, and not in the url. That way any logged in user can change the id in url and see other user's data

Comment: good. thank you. i was planning on using sessions. as from what i understand from what i've read it's more secure anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your foreign keys are setup correctly so that the data is linked to the `user_id (PK)` then it should be fine. Alternatively you can setup a `user_roles` table which contains access rights.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and how I have been programming, yes. If you are looking for extra security, perhaps check the user's password/salt against what is in the database.

Comment: But that's not extra security, that's the basis of any login isn't it? so that's primitive security to start with. Extra security is something else

Comment: My mistake, I wrote before I thought.

Answer (score 0):

> l i need to do is make sure the queries pull only the data based off their unique id

I'm not sure what you mean by this, but it is too a general/broad statement to be either bad or good. It really depends on the system you're building. This is by no means a generally applicable statement.

Now in your current set-up this looks somewhat correct, but in the long-ish term you might need some data be public, or at least accessible by several people. This is impossible in your current design.

I would split the access and content, as they are separate things. Save what users (or look up a role-based pattern) have access to what data in separate tables, so you can build on what you have later, and add multiple user functionality.

This could become a long discussion, so I'll end with this: The bottomline with all database design is that you should save your information in a way that represents logical units, as it is in the real world (Yes, I'm taking some shortcuts here). So coupling a username to an id seems normal. But making the connection between a job and a user isn't that logical per se. A job can be visible to multiple users, no sweat. Or more then one user could have added the information. You could say that only 1 user is the 'owner' of a job or any other piece of data, but it seems too restrictive to make your access control purely out of who "owns" the data.

But then again, it is only a warning for the future. If you never need this, you don't.

Comment: think i understand what our saying. what i'm working on is something like a job search. a way to keep track of applications submitted to companies, contacts (ie:recruiters), ability to upload resumes, etc.  so other then the pages, dashboard, contacts applications pages, etc, each of those need to pull the specific users data and display.

Comment: So what you're currently having seems fine, because you are currently showing 1 user with coupled data. But as soon as one user has several jobs, or a job belongs to a company belongs to an HR-team, you'd get in trouble if you rely on "unique id" (single!) instead of a more complicated system. There is no ready-made drop-in system to do access-control for every case I can link you to, just keep in mind what features you might need in the future :)

Comment: Okay, so now you have me worried. let's say john has 8 jobs entered but june only has 3. then using a unique id won't work?

Comment: No, sure, but what if john and june both work for "bigCompany", and they both should be allowed to see all 11 jobs? Then you can't just take the ID.

Comment: bare with me, as i'm reading through the help file of the site to figure out how this comment thing works! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I have lots more to say, I've added some final thoughts to the answer that should help you along. If all this is really too confusing, you might want to ease into it first by just trying what you have, maybe reading up on database design: how to go from real world to objects-in-a-database. It's a big area so it's not going to be explained just in these comments ;)

Comment: let's try this. John enters a company. in the database, there is a table for companies. In that table among all the columns is a column called user_id. this row would then get the id of said user. in this case john. the companies table looks like:
    client_id
    client_date_created
    client_date_modified
    client_name
    client_address_1
    client_address_2
    client_city
    client_state
    client_zip
    client_phone
    client_email
    client_web
    client_interview
    user_id

So if June would enter the same company, her id would then go into the user_id table.

Answer (score 0):

You could have multiple databases, one per user. You'll need to have a way to do schema changes & upgrades though, like phinx. I wouldn't recommend this unless you foresee users having multiple users on their own account.

Comment: multiple *databases* ? Really?

Comment: Yes, for example a program that allows you to alter the schema per user, many CRM's do this, like salesforce or Odoo, the two most popular ones

Comment: It would appear that this is very probably out of scope for this question. Your answers doesn't add a whole lot for digging up a very old question....